# Adding List Parameter to @Subselect entity using @FilterDef

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, subquery, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to add a list parameter for `@Subselect` entity.

In @ParamDef: The param is `'locations'`, it's type: `List<String>`

I tried different options for 'type' inside @ParamDef but no one works.
Here are the options that i tried:

- list
- java.util.List
- java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- List<String>

What is the type that i should put?

P.S: Hibernate version: 5.6.4.Final

```java
import lombok.Data;
import net.ccc.apps.config.CSVToListConverter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Immutable
@Data
@FilterDef(name = "personnelActiveFilter", parameters = {
    @ParamDef(name = "locations", type = "List<String>"),
    @ParamDef(name = "useLocationFilter", type = "boolean")
})
@Subselect(
    " SELECT e.id, e.group_no, e.badge_no, e.email, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.date_of_birth, e.sex_id, e.initial_hub_id, \n" +
    " STRING_AGG(c.name, ', ') AS nationalities_str, STRING_AGG(c.name, ',') AS nationalities, \n" +
    " ash.location, ash.pay_status, ash.area_date, ash.group_date, ash.contract_date, ash.contract_end_date AS termination_date \n" +
    " FROM employee e \n" +
    " INNER JOIN \n" +
    "   ( \n" +
    "     SELECT employee_id, location, pay_status, area_date, group_date, contract_date, contract_end_date FROM action_sheet_header \n" +
    "     WHERE (employee_id, effective_date) IN ( \n" +
    "       SELECT employee_id, MAX(effective_date) AS max_effective_date \n" +
    "       FROM action_sheet_header \n" +
    "       WHERE (:personnelActiveFilter.useLocationFilter = true AND location IN :personnelActiveFilter.locations AND status = 'C' AND active = true AND released = false) \n" +
    "       OR (:personnelActiveFilter.useLocationFilter = false AND status = 'C' AND active = true AND released = false) \n" +
    "       GROUP BY employee_id, location \n" +
    "     ) \n" +
    "   ) ash \n" +
    " ON e.id = ash.employee_id \n" +
    " LEFT JOIN nationality na \n" +
    "   INNER JOIN country c ON na.country_id = c.code ON na.employee_id = e.id \n" +
    " GROUP BY e.id, ash.location, ash.pay_status, ash.area_date, ash.group_date, ash.contract_date, ash.contract_end_date \n" +
    " ORDER BY e.id"
)
public class PersonnelActive implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String groupNo;
    private String badgeNo;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String sexId;
    private String initialHubId;
    private String nationalitiesStr;
    @Convert(converter = CSVToListConverter.class)
    private List<String> nationalities;
    private String location;
    private String payStatus;
    private LocalDate areaDate;
    private LocalDate groupDate;
    private LocalDate contractDate;
    private LocalDate terminationDate;
}
```